# Faster Computation for Double For Relative Position Loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix

I have the following problem of computing the relative position of an array X[n]:

[Equation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDqeT.png)

I am currently doing the following computation:

Let's take `X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, then:

```
D = []
for idx1 in range(0,len(X)):
    aux = []
    for idx2 in range(idx1, len(X)):
        aux.append(np.sign(X[idx1]-X[idx2]))
    D.append(np.sum(aux))
```

The output of this code is:

`D = [-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]`

However, for too long X arrays, this computation is VERY slow! Do any one have any suggestion on how to make it faster? Parall is not that easy two because of the intermediate "aux" step! I was thinking about some matrix approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `X` to a `np.array` type before.

```py
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

And then do a vectorized loop like this:

```py
D = [np.sum(np.sign(X[idx1]-X[idx1:])) for idx1 in range(0,len(X))]
```

It should be much faster.

Please note that there is probably a more clever algorithm. This one compute the result in `O(n^2)` time (where `n = len(X)`).

Comment: That make it faster Jerôme Richard. Yes, this algorithm is a top-down algorithm, which is very computationally inefficient! Thanks a lot for sharing your solution. Thank you too @Mark Mayer! Both solutions are great!